# Rodar o comando shell_exec com UTF-8 em PHP

Tags: php, shell, utf-8

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em linguagem PHP e utilizo o comando [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shell-exec.php), porém quando retorno alguma mensagem com acentuação, ele não mostra o caractere.

Exemplo:

Comando: `<?=shell_exec('tasklist /fi "pid eq '.getmypid().'" ')?>`

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como printar a mensagem acima com UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php) para fazer isso. Desta forma:

```
$locale = 'pt_BR.UTF-8';
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale); // LC_ALL informa que tudo abaixo deste código será configurado para pt_BR.UTF-8
putenv('LC_ALL='.$locale);    
shell_exec('tasklist /fi "pid eq '.getmypid().'" ');
```

**Edit**

Estive dando uma pesquisada e descobri que o `setlocale` depende da configuração do servidor.
Se por acaso não funcionar com 'pt_BR', tente usar o 'en_US' que é o padrão de muitos servidores.

Você também pode usar variações, assim:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8', 'en_US.UTF8', 'en.UTF-8', 'en.UTF8');
```

**Edit 2**

Uma outra opção é usar o [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php):

```
$saida = shell_exec('tasklist /fi "pid eq '.getmypid().'" ');
$saida = utf8_encode($saida);
echo $saida;
```

Tente desta forma também:

```
$saida = shell_exec('tasklist /fi "pid eq '.getmypid().'" ');
$saida = utf8_encode($saida);

foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){ 
       $saida = mb_convert_encoding($saida, 'UTF-8', $chr);    
}
```

Referencias:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961870/php-exec-change-encoding)

[Problemas com setlocale](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setlocale.php#46640)

Comment: Fiz essas alterações que você comentou e não funcionou, não me  retornou em UTF-8 a mensagem. Continua sendo exibido do mesmo jeito

Comment: @Piupz tem uma outra opção.

Comment: @Piupz tente com edit 2

Comment: Ele me retornou [assim](https://i.imgur.com/ClzwfxH.png), ainda não está em UTF-8 =/

Comment: @Piupz ok! O problema é que o servidor não está configurado para utf8. Vou ver se consigo fazer algo quanto a isso.

Comment: @Piupz da uma olhada na edição e veja se resolve agora.

Comment: Tem que mudar o locale do shell, não do PHP. Ou então, simplesmente pegar o resultado do shell e converter na exibição, que é muito mais simples (que é praticamente o final da resposta). Agora, antes de mais nada está faltando na pergunta alguma coisa confirmando o locale atual do shell.

Comment: @Bacco tem rasão. Acho que um `echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);` mostra qual é a locali.